# Terraform keep saying variable not defined though its defined

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I am trying to create a resource in azure via `Terraform`. Even though I have declared all required variables, its erroring out. I am using `modules` for the same...

**Here is the below code that I tried:**

**My Module's `Bastion/main.tf` that used to create resource:**

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "syn_pip" {
  name                = "pip-${var.prefix}-${var.postfix}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  allocation_method = var.bastion_allocation_method
  sku = var.bastion_sku_type
}
```

**My modules's `Bastion/variables.tf` :**

```
variable "bastion_allocation_method" {
  type = string
  description = "allocation method for bastion"
}

variable "bastion_sku_type" {
  type = string
  description = "sku to be used for bastion"
}
```

**My root module `bastion.tf` :**

```
module "bastion" {
  source = "../modules/bastion"
  rg_name  = module.resource_group.name
  location = module.resource_group.location
  allocation_method = var.bastion_allocation_method
  sku = var.bastion_sku_type
  prefix  = var.prefix
  postfix = random_string.postfix.result
  subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.bastion_subnet.id
}
```

**root module's `variable.tf`:**

```
variable "bastion_allocation_method" {
  type = string
}

variable "bastion_sku_type" {
  type = string
}
```

**my `terraform.tfvars` which passed to `terraform plan` :**

```
"bastion_allocation_method": "Static",
"bastion_sku_type": "Standard"
```

**Error that I get:**

```
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   on bastion.tf line 1, in module "bastion":
│    1: module "bastion" {
│ 
│ The argument "bastion_allocation_method" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   on bastion.tf line 1, in module "bastion":
│    1: module "bastion" {
│ 
│ The argument "bastion_sku_type" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on bastion.tf line 7, in module "bastion":
│    7:   allocation_method = var.bastion_allocation_method
│ 
│ An argument named "allocation_method" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on bastion.tf line 8, in module "bastion":
│    8:   sku = var.bastion_sku_type
│ 
│ An argument named "sku" is not expected here.
╵

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Can someone suggest, what is the mistake I am doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Bastion` module in the variables.tf you specify the arguments

```
variable "bastion_allocation_method" {
  ...
}

variable "bastion_sku_type" {
  ...
}
```

In your case your module expects the vars `bastion_allocation_method` and `bastion_sku_type`

But when you call the module, you dont pass the variable names properly

```
module "bastion" {
  source = "../modules/bastion"
  ...
  allocation_method = var.bastion_allocation_method
  sku = var.bastion_sku_type
  ...
}
```

Use instead

```
module "bastion" {
  source = "../modules/bastion"
  ...
  bastion_allocation_method = var.bastion_allocation_method
  bastion_sku_type = var.bastion_sku_type
  ...
}
```

The variable assignments that you pass in module clause should match the definitions in the module's variables.tf

Comment: Thanks for reply, oh yeah what silly thing I missed, let me try this and let you know

Comment: @asp Greetings, so did it solve the issue? Or should I make some adjustments?

Comment: Yes accepted your suggestion as answer. Apologies for delayed reply